# Angular disable checkbox based on other checkbox value reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to disable the checkbox based on the other checkboxes value.
only one of them can be enabled.

I'm getting this error when enabling one of them, as the subscribed: value is coming in numerously.

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:191:32)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:22)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:26)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:18)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39:25)
    at EventEmitter_.emit (core.mjs:22784:15)
    at FormControl.disable (forms.mjs:2164:31)
    at Object.next (saxo-browser.component.ts:95:52)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:22)
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.
this is my code,

component:

```js
  private initForm(): void {
    this.settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstValue:[false],
      secondValue: [false]
    });

    this.settingsForm.get('firstValue').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === true) {
        this.settingsForm.get('secondValue').disable()
      } else {
        this.settingsForm.get('secondValue').enable();
      }
    });
    
    this.settingsForm.get('secondValue').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === true) {
        this.settingsForm.get('firstValue').disable()
      } else {
        this.settingsForm.get('firstValue').enable();
      }
    });
  }
```

html:

```html
    <form name="settingsForm" novalidate [formGroup]="settingsForm">
        <label class="switch">
            <input formControlName="firstValue" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="switch">
            <input formControlName="secondValue" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </form
```

Comment: Have you considered just using the input type attribute `type="radio"`? This is the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: i havent however, the previous design had 2 checkboxes so im just trying to do the same with also 2 checkboxes

Comment: You can style them to look the same if that helps. FYI you're getting this error because every time 1 changes, you update 2, which triggers 2 to update 1... in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not trigger the valuechanges with this

```
enable({emitEvent:false}) // same for disable
```

And as Alex said, a radio button would be better in this case.